# nVidia Quadro 600 on Debian (stable) Twinview

Tags: drivers, debian-squeeze, nvidia-quadro

I want to run Debian stable on a 64-Bit (amd64) system and enable twinview on the graphics board `nVidia Quadro 600`.
The default installed driver works for one screen. After installing the Nvidia* packages and running `nvidia-xconfig` the x-server no longer comes up.   One solution might be downloading and building the actual driver from the nVidia-Homepage. But, does anyone know a better (debian included) solution? I can not find any package (stable or backported) that supports this graphics board.

Maybe the following is of interest: `lspci|grep -i nvidia` results in

```
0f:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation Device 0df8 (rev a1)
```

Okay found some details: Looking at [debian squeeze-backports package info](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze-backports/nvidia-glx) showed that kernel 275.36 is in the backports-package, which supports Quadro 600 by [nVidia](http://www.nvidia.de/object/linux-display-amd64-275.36-driver-de.html).
Further there is a [database](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/gamedev/docs/device_ids_may11.txt), which explains, that the `nVidia Corporation Device 0df8 (rev a1)` is the `Quadro 600`?

Comment: How can I mark this question as solved? (By myself)? Sorry for asking - was hoping to get the needed help faster.

Comment: By posting an answer below. Wait a while and you can accept your own answer.